# SQL Server create primary key constraint duplicate key error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have been experiencing some strange behaviour with one of my SQL commands taken from one of our stored procedures.

This command follows the below order of execution:

> 1) Drop table
>
> 2) Select * into table name from live server
>
> 3) Alter table to apply PK - this step fails once out of 4 daily executions

My SQL statement:

```
 IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N' 
 [inf].[tblBase_MyTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
 DROP TABLE [inf].[tblBase_MyTable]

 SELECT * INTO [inf].[tblBase_MyTable]
 FROM LiveServer.KMS_ALLOCATION WITH (NOLOCK)

 ALTER TABLE [inf].[tblBase_MyTable] ADD  
 CONSTRAINT [PK_KMS_ALLOCATION] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
 (
   [ID] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = 
 OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

 GRANT SELECT ON [inf].[tblBase_MyTable] TO ourGroup
```

This is very strange considering the table is dropped, and I thought the indexes / keys would also be dropped. However I get this error at the same time every day. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Error:

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'inf.tblBase_MyTable' and the index name 'PK_KMS_ALLOCATION'.

Comment: It seems duplicate records are there in the column you are creating PK for. As PK column do not allow duplicates, you first need to remove duplicates from the table and then create the PK.

Comment: but the table is dropped?

Comment: there are no duplicates on this key within the live system

Comment: In your step-2, you are inserting records first before creating the PK.

Comment: yes thats to improve insert speed, the data is pulled directly from the live system table within which there is no duplicates on this key.

Comment: The script runs fine 3 out of 4 times, this key is unique in the source system

Comment: Be sure there is no duplicate records on `LiveServer.KMS_ALLOCATION` table.

Comment: I am positive of this. The PK is scripted from the live system

Comment: Try to put `Go` After each script, and try again.

Comment: Try this one SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM [inf].[tblBase_MyTable]
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 Is there any record in the result?

Comment: Is there a chance that `ID`-values of records in `LiveServer.KMS_ALLOCATION` are updated/changed during the execution of the SELECT INTO query?

Comment: Lets assume I have tried all of the basic thinbgs you are suggesting. and I can say that there are  no duplicates on ID in the source. So when my tabvle is dropped aloing witht the keys, I am then inserting new data at every execution. and then creatiung the key

Comment: no there are no duplicates. I have checked all of the basics

Comment: The `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint can cause dirty reads, a symptom of which can sometimes be duplicate reads. Are there `UPDATE` statements running on the live system at the same time that you're selecting the data from it?

Comment: Try without "NOLOCK". Did you check the database state? Try also "DBCC CHECKDB"

Comment: Removing NOLOCK might cause the live system to "hang" during the SELECT INTO statement... Don't know if this solution is acceptable for the OP, especially if the table is quite large...

Comment: Yes the table is very large and I m using NOLOCK to prevent the system from hanging. howevere I am not using SNAPSHOT READ committed. And yes the data can change when I am reading in from the source. @Diado the most plausibe theory so far. Should I look to migrate onto a snapshot model to prevernt this?

Comment: *If* updates to the underlying data are causing duplicate reads due to the use of `NOLOCK`, then yes, using snapshot isolation would solve it, but you might need to do some more digging just to confirm that's actually the cause

Comment: Can you please check another issue before creating PK that is the column ID is allowing NULL or not. If NULL allowed, try to create PK after set the column ID to NOT NULL.

Comment: @Diado yes that where I am at with it, It's looking like data changes undelying the READ COMMITTED model is the issue. I will look to mograte to a SNAPSHOT

Comment: Try "DBCC CHECKDB WITH DATA_PURITY" on your live database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having reviewed various helpful comments here, I have decided against (for now) implementing SNAPSHOT isolation as this interface does not make use of a proper staging environment.

To move to this would mean either creating a staging area and setting that database to READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT isolation, and a rebuild of the entire interface.

To that end and on the basis of saving development time, we have opted for ensuring that any ghost reads where dupes could be brought across from the source are handled before applying the PK.

This is by no means an ideal solution in terms of performance on the target server but will provide some headroom for now and certainly remove the previous error.

SQL approach below:

```
DECLARE @ALLOCTABLE TABLE 
(SEQ INT, ID NVARCHAR(1000), CLASSID NVARCHAR(1000), [VERSION] NVARCHAR(25), [TYPE] 
NVARCHAR(100), VERSIONSEQUENCE NVARCHAR(100), VERSIONSEQUENCE_TO NVARCHAR(100), 
BRANCHID NVARCHAR(100), ISDELETED INT, RESOURCE_CLASS NVARCHAR(25), RESOURCE_ID 
NVARCHAR(100), WARD_ID NVARCHAR(100), ISCOMPLETE INT, TASK_ID NVARCHAR(100));

------- ALLOCATION
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[inf]. 
[tblBase_MyTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [inf].[tblBase_MyTable]

SELECT * INTO [inf].[tblBase_MyTable]
FROM LiveServer.KMS_ALLOCATION WITH (NOLOCK)

INSERT INTO @ALLOCTABLE
SELECT *
  FROM
   (SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ISCOMPLETE DESC) SEQ, AL.*
   FROM [inf].[tblBase_MyTable] AL
 )DUPS
 WHERE SEQ >1

 DELETE FROM [inf].[tblBase_MyTable]
 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @ALLOCTABLE)
 AND ISCOMPLETE = 0

ALTER TABLE [inf].[tblBase_MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[PK_KMS_ALLOCATION] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
  (
   [ID] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

GRANT SELECT ON [inf].[tblBase_MyTable] TO OurGroup
```

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate keys in **[inf].[tblBase_MyTable]** table are actually possible thanks to the **WITH (NOLOCK)** hint which allows "dirty reads". Have a look at blog which describes this in detail: [SQL Server NOLOCK Hint & other poor ideas](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidlean/2009/04/05/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas/):

> **What many people think NOLOCK is doing**
>
> Most people think the NOLOCK hint just reads rows & doesn’t have to
>   wait till others have committed their updates or selects. If someone
>   is updating, that is OK. If they’ve changed a value then 99.999% of
>   the time they will commit, so it’s OK to read it before they commit.
>   If they haven’t changed the record yet then it saves me waiting, its
>   like my transaction happened before theirs did.
>
> **The Problem**
>
> The issue is that transactions do more than just update the row. Often
>   they require an index to be updated OR they run out of space on the
>   data page. This may require new pages to be allocated & existing rows
>   on that page to be moved, called a PageSplit. It is possible for your
>   select to completely miss a number of rows &/or count other rows
>   twice.

Comment: Although very useful information I am accutely aware of the trade off here

Comment: How big is the source table? How frequently data is changed? Have you considered CDC?

Answer (score 0):

Well... you might have to repeat creating the new table and filling it until the check-query from @DarkoMartinovic does not return duplicates. Only then you can continue to add the PK. But this solution might cause heavy load on your live system. And you nave no guarantee that you have a 1:1 copy of the data as well.

Comment: I agree this would place heavy load onto the system, would it be bettr therefore to move to a READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT ISOLATION model?

Comment: You might certainly try that. @Diado also pointed it out as a possible solution. If it works, you have guarantee that you have a valid copy of the data. However, I have little experience with various isolation levels, so I cannot ad-hoc provide any do's and don'ts in that respect.